# Overstaying visa waiver while waiting for residency permit in Belgium?

Tags: resident-permit, student-visa, belgium

I'm an Australian citizen who entered Belgium under Schengen Visa waiver program and applied for residency permit (autorisation de séjour) to study here for a year. However, application processing is taking longer than expected and now my 90 days come to an end.

My understanding is, the proper thing to do in this situation is to leave and abandon my application. To my best knowledge, having a pending application with the foreigners office (Bureau des Étrangers) does not in itself allow me to stay.

Are there any other legal options? Has someone been in this situation before? (In Belgium or perhaps a different Schengen country) My current plan is to wait for a response and, if it's negative, leave and take the consequences of overstaying. (I'm hoping this doesn't lower a chance of positive response)

Thanks for your help!